# ionic env becomes unstable after updating nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

My ionic environment becomes unstable after updation nodejs from v8.1 to v12..
Any idea what all i have to update?

[abc]$ ionic cordova emulate android

> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'
> Require stack:
> -

```
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/index.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/index.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/run-impl.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /home/user/workspace1/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/tmp/ng-wzIyd3/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        
       ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 127.
```

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/uid": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.2.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.2.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-hot-code-push-plugin": "1.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-unique-device-id2": "2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1000.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.28",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.16",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.30",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-hot-code-push-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Update Ionic to the latest version: `npm install -g ionic@latest`
2. Remove `node_modules` folder, then `npm install` to put it back all the dependencies with the new Ionic version reflected with the updated node version.

Comment: Thanks @dev.doc
Unfortunately it did not help. Any other thoughts..

Comment: Node modules deleted and again got restored after npm install ...but the error still remains same.I checked latest package.json and previous version. Its no different....
Any other thoughts..?

Comment: I see, try to these please:

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
`npm install -g @angular/cli`
`npm install`

If still persist, I would generate a new project, make it run and if it works then compare the `package.json` to your project. Mine package looks different than yours, I would move the following packages from `devDepencies` to `dependencies`:
`"@angular/cli": "^8.3.28"`
`"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.16"`

I noticed that the version of these dependencies differs from mine (~9.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

@dev.doc ...Highly appreciate your response...

There is change in error,I hope it past the error

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@latest
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

which brings to different error now..

```
> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
See "/tmp/ng-ZAbd9i/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 127.
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
...details--------
[error] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (../workspace/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:68:9)
    at ..ion/mygrd/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:118:17
    at ..ion/mygrd/node_modules/@angular/compiler-
```

My updated package.json reflects the version..it know its slightly higher that your version..
"@angular/cli": "^10.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.4"